# Does this family of polynomials have a name?

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, reference-request

I have stumbled across this family of polynomials in $n$ variables (say, in $ R[x_1,\dots, x_n]$ for $R$ a commutative ring with one) while working on a certain seemingly unrelated problem, and I was wondering (mostly out of curiosity) whether this family has a known name in the literature (I presume most likely in combinatorics).

The family is as follows: for a given $r$-tuple $T = (a_1,\dots,a_r)$ of (possibly repeated) integers from $1$ to $n$ we denote $x_T := x_{a_1}\dots x_{a_r}$ the monomial of degree $r$ given by $T$. Let $S_n$ be the set of tuples of integers (of any length) from $1$ to $n$ whose sum is $n$ (i.e partitions of $n$, but not necessarily in decreasing order). Then:

$$p_n(x_1,\dots,x_n) := \sum_{T \in S_n}x_T.$$

For example, for $n = 3$ we have $S_3 = \{(3), (2,1), (1,2), (1,1,1)\}$ and so
$$p_3(x_1,x_2,x_3) = x_3 + x_2x_1 + x_1x_2 + x_1^3 = x_3 + 2x_1x_2 + x_1^3.$$

Similarly,

$$p_4(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) = x_4 + 2x_3x_1 + 3x_2x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_1^4.$$

These should also be given by the following recurrence relation (considering $R[x_1,\dots,x_k] \subset R[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ for $k \le n$):

$$p_n = x_n + \sum_{j=1}^{n-1}x_{n-j}p_{j}$$

and $p_1 = x_1$.